# iframe height constrained when set in CSS or tag

Tags: html, iframe

For some reason my iframe height is constrained, whether I set it in CSS or in the tag. I'm not sure what this is all about and searches reveal nothing. I'm not sure what to do at this point and may need to abandoned the embeds. Also, when I force the container to 960px (the height of the video) it will get a scroll bar with no overflow options defined. Weird.

http://jordan.rave5.com/tmpstuff/

```
                    <div class="left-large-box">
                        <div class="large-box">
                            <div class="large-box-content">
                                <div class="content-full">
                                    <div class="column-header">
                                        <div class="column-icon">
                                            Title here
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <p><iframe width="690" height="388" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/jH7f6e9FsLc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box-end"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your style sheet `blue.css` you apply `height: auto;` to all elements, that overrides the `height` attribute of the iframe. You can still use a style on the element to set the height though.

If you remove the `height: auto`, the `height` attribute works also.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated! I missed that height auto cause of the condensed class.